# Table not found , while using sqlite database from asset folder in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite database browser to create sqlite database. I copied the database in my project asset/databases/ folder.

Below is the dbhelper class i am using  , the database is checked , it is opened , but on quering it is saying alarms_info table not found . I have this table in my database.

```
public class LatestHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  

 private static String DB_NAME = "alarms";  
 private SQLiteDatabase db;  
 private final Context context;  
 private String DB_PATH;  

 private static final String TABLE_ALARMS ="alarms_info";
 private static final String ALARM_ID ="_id";
 private static final String ALARM_CODE ="alarm_code";
 private static final String PRIORITY ="alarm_priority";
 private static final String USER_MESSAGE ="user_message";
 private static final String PROMPT_MESSAGE ="prompt_message";

 public LatestHelper(Context context) {  
  super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);  
  this.context = context;  
  DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";  
 }  

 public void createDataBase() throws IOException {  

  boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();  
  if (dbExist) {  

  } else {  
   this.getReadableDatabase();  
   try {  
    copyDataBase();  
   } catch (IOException e) {  
    throw new Error("Error copying database");  
   }  
  }  
 }  

 private boolean checkDataBase() {  
  File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);  
  return dbFile.exists();  
 }  

 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {  

  InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);  
  String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
  OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);  
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
  int length;  
  while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
   myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);  
  }  

  // Close the streams  
  myOutput.flush();  
  myOutput.close();  
  myInput.close();  

 }  

/* public Cursor getData() {  
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
  db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM master", null);  
   // Note: Master is the one table in External db. Here we trying to access the records of table from external db.  
  return c;  
 } */ 

 public Alarmsinfo getalarminfo(int id)
 {
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    Alarmsinfo alarminfo = new Alarmsinfo();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
    System.out.println("manav"+db);
    String query = "SELECT "+ALARM_CODE+","+PRIORITY+","+USER_MESSAGE+","+PROMPT_MESSAGE+" FROM "+TABLE_ALARMS+" WHERE "+ALARM_ID+" = "+id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            alarminfo.setAlarm_code(cursor.getString(0));
            alarminfo.setPriority(cursor.getInt(1));
            alarminfo.setMsg(cursor.getString(2));
            alarminfo.setPrompt_msg(cursor.getString(3));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return alarminfo;

 }
```

Below is the logcat :

```
E/SQLiteLog(25136): (1) no such table: alarms_info

D/AndroidRuntime(25136): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(25136): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d92300)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(25136): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3595)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4088)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16984)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3590)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    ... 11 more

E/AndroidRuntime(25136): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: alarms_info (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT alarm_code,alarm_priority,user_message,prompt_message FROM alarms_info WHERE _id = 1

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at com.example.mydialysis.handlers.LatestHelper.getalarminfo(LatestHelper.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at com.example.mydialysis.Dashboard.addalarm(Dashboard.java:95)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    at com.example.mydialysis.Dashboard.oncritical(Dashboard.java:79)

E/AndroidRuntime(25136):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Check if your table name contain any extra spaces or not.

Comment: Checked , its exactly the same.

Comment: Can you Post logcat message also.

Comment: I have even tried sqliteassethelper library , but same error. I am using android 4.1

Comment: I think you havnt save your table.After creating the table manually with sqlite browser you have to press the save button.Then copy it to your asset folder.Delete the old one...and create a fresh table and dont forget to save it.

Comment: There is no save button in sqlite browser , but there is write changes button . I created a new table , deleted the old one , pressed write changes button. Same error

Comment: i am having the same error . did you get the answer?